# Slide in another div, from right to left, and adjust the height animated (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div with a login form and a button for "forgot password".
I have another div with the forgot password form, i want to slide in, in front of the login div and adjustig the height, when "forgot button" is clicked.
The entire box should be positioned

Illustration:
[image: Illustration]

The HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="box">
        <div id="log_in">
            <p>LOG IN FORM</p>
            <p>LOG IN FORM</p>
            <p>LOG IN FORM</p>
            <p>LOG IN FORM</p>
            <p>LOG IN FORM</p>
            <div id="forgot">Forgot password?</div>
        </div>
        <div id="forgot_form">
            <p>FORGOT FORM</p>
            <p>FORGOT FORM</p>
            <p>FORGOT FORM</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content{
  background-color: blue;
  width:100%;
  height:900px;
}
#box{
  width: 200px;
  position: relative; 
  top: 20px; 
  left: 14px; 
  display: block;
  border:2px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
#forgot{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}
```

This is what i got so far in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#forgot_form").css({'display':'none'});
    $("#forgot").on("click", function () {
        $("#log_in").css({'display':'none'});
        $("#forgot_form").css({'display':'block'});
        $("#forgot_form").css({"left":"200px"}).animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/rLdfmf4n/4/

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to just use CSS animation to do what you're trying to do. Try adding this to your CSS file

```
#forgot_form {
position: absolute;
left: -200px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
-webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
animation-delay: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
100% { left: 0; }
}

@keyframes slide {
100% { left: 0; }
}
```

Now you would just have to write some JQuery to trigger the animation when clicked on the link. (Hint: use toggleClass())

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the margin-left and margin-right to auto in css...when you give margins it automatically sets the form in its position

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope this help you

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#forgot").on("click", function () {
        $("#log_in").css({'display':'none'});
        $("#forgot_form").css({'display':'block'});
        $("#forgot_form").animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

```css
#content{
  background-color: blue;
  width:100%;
  height:900px;
}
#box{
    width: 200px;
  position: relative; 
  top: 20px; 
  left: 14px; 
  display: block;
  border:2px solid red;
   background-color: white;
   padding: 5px;
}
#log_in{

}
#forgot{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}
#forgot_form{
  
   position: relative;
    left: 220px;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div id="box">
    <div id="log_in">
      <p>LOG IN FORM</p>
      <p>LOG IN FORM</p>
      <p>LOG IN FORM</p>
      <p>LOG IN FORM</p>
      <p>LOG IN FORM</p>
      <div id="forgot">Forgot password?</div>
    </div>
    <div id="forgot_form">
     <p>FORGOT FORM</p>
     <p>FORGOT FORM</p>
     <p>FORGOT FORM</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

hope this help you.